# How to I put Sharepoint OOTB calendar into my custom webpart?

Tags: sharepoint

As the same title of question, how can i put or use sharepoint OOTB calendar in my visual webpart ?

I am so sorry if my question is not clear or dupplicate or make anybody confuse. I am very new in Sharepoint. I work in Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

If you want only calendar then add following line of code in webpart class in `CreateChildControls`method.

```
    Calendar calender = new Calendar();
    control.Controls.Add(calender);
```

Complete method will look like this.

```
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
        Controls.Add(control);
        Calendar calender = new Calendar();
        control.Controls.Add(calender);
    }
```

If you want calendar view then add following line of code in webpart class `CreateChildControls`method.

```
   SPCalendarView calenderview = new SPCalendarView();
    control.Controls.Add(calenderview);
```

Complete method will look like this.

```
  protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
        Controls.Add(control);
        SPCalendarView calenderview = new SPCalendarView();
        control.Controls.Add(calenderview);
    }
}
```

Using properties and methods of both class you can achieve your task.